# GWT 2.6.1 compilation error | Unable to find Entrypoint

Tags: gwt, compiler-errors, smartgwt

i'm struggling since a couple of days ago in the attempt to resuscitate an old GWT application (which version is not updatable due to budget reasons).

In particular i've found several issues during the compilation phase.

This is what is blocking me:

*Compiling module OctoMonitor Validating units: Ignored 200 units with compilation errors in first pass. Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors. Finding entry point classes [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.lynxspa.octomonitor.frontend.client.OctoMonitorEntryPoint' [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'com.lynxspa.octomonitor.frontend.client.OctoMonitorEntryPoint' is really what you meant [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots [ERROR] Compiler returned false [WARN] continuing to serve previous version*

I've checked my source folder (which is referred in classpath) and my .gwt.xml file is in the parent folder of my EntryPoint class.

source folder:

- .gwt.xml file
- client folder (containing EntryPoint Class)

I've also checked in project > preference > build path > source that every entry does not have any excluded resource anymore.

Ideas?

Comment: The EntryPoint is not found cause of errors. Don't think, that this is a problem related to a build path issue. Set the logLevel to TRACE and rerun the compile. This should list all errors.

Comment: I'll tell you this - you've got 200 compilation errors in the first pass. Some of those errors actually resolve themselves in the second pass, but in my experience, it's best to resolve them straight away. As El Hoss said, you'll want to at least get a list of those errors before continuing. Chances are you'll want to clean them up too.

Comment: Try show your gwt project structure and the entrypoint java source code, for know more about the problem.